# Como é feito o cálculo do IMPACTO no perfíl?

Tags: suporte, perfil

Como é feito o cálculo do IMPACTO?
Tenho uma pergunta, sem nenhuma resposta, visualizada 12 vezes e meu IMPACTO acusa aproximadamente 11 pessoas ajudadas.

Não entendi!

Comment: Nesse outro perfíl tenho essa pergunta, nenhuma resposta e aproximadamente 2 pessoas ajudadas??????

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Acho que você acabou de achar um erro na tradução do SOpt. :)

O texto deveria dizer "XX pessoas **alcançadas**", ou algum sinônimo disso (não atingidas, senão fica parecendo que você arremessou uma pedra nelas, hehe).

O *tooltip* que aparece quando você passa o mouse sobre o impacto também está com a tradução um pouco distorcida. Atualmente diz o seguinte:

> Estimativa de quantas vezes seus posts ajudaram outros (baseado no
>   número de visitas às suas perguntas e respostas com pontuação alta)

Mas o texto do SOen é o seguinte:

> Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on
>   page views of your questions and questions where you wrote
>   highly-ranked answers)

Ou seja, não é quantas pessoas você **ajudou** (até porque isso é impossível de se medir), mas quantas pessoas você **pode ter ajudado**, que é uma estimativa da quantidade de pessoas que leram suas perguntas e suas respostas com muitos votos. São levadas em consideração:

- Perguntas

  - Não deletadas apenas
- Respostas - Vizualizações da respectiva pergunta para as perguntas que:

  - Não foram deletadas E
  - Possuem pontuação > 0 E
  - Também atendem um ou mais dos seguintes critérios:

    - Uma das respostas no Top 3 OU
    - Foi a resposta aceita OU
    - Possui pontuação > 5 OU
    - Possui ao menos 20% dos votos totais

No seu caso específico, enquanto escrevo essa resposta, a pergunta foi vizualizada 24 vezes, e seu impacto no meta é exatamente 24. Da mesma forma, seu impacto no SOpt é 17, e sua pergunta tem 17 vizualizações. Imagino que a diferença que você encontrou (12 ~ 11) seja em virtude de diferenças no tempo de atualização de cada uma das contagens.

Os critérios acima, uma descrição e a discussão detalhada desse recurso podem ser encontrados no Meta SE aqui (em inglês):

[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

Edit:

Em relação à tradução, acho que realmente deve ser revista. Isso porque no link acima está explicitamente definido que **ajudado** é muito forte para uma estimativa baseada apenas em page views. De fato, a procura pelo termo ideal foi uma das coisas que motivou a criação da pergunta no SE, e por fim escolheram *reached*, e não *helped*.

Comment: Ainda assim, para **Pessoas que pode ter ajudado**, acredito que perguntas só poderiam ser contabilizadas para esse contador a partir do momento que ela teve uma resposta aceita ou com pontuação boa. Do contrário ela é só mais uma dúvida não respondida.

Comment: Estava vendo o [histórico](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40274408?qt=ajudada) de traduções e o texto anterior estava como *alcançadas*. Aparentemente foi o Gabe que mudou para *ajudadas*.

Comment: Realmente. Resta saber se ele alterou simplesmente porque é mais bonito (que é mesmo), ou se foi levando em consideração o contexto original mas aplicando o princípio "SOpt não é SOen". E aí, @Gabe?