# Pessoas ajudadas

Tags: debate, tradução, localização, perfil

Na página de perfil de cada usuário existe uma secção de estatísticas que indica o número total de:

- `Respostas` - Traduzido do texto em inglês do SOen - **Answers**
- `Perguntas` - Traduzido do texto em inglês do SOen - **Questions**
- `Pessoas ajudadas` - Traduzido do texto em inglês do SOen - **People reached**

Como no exemplo da imagem abaixo. No então eu acho que a tradução do texto - `pessoas ajudadas` não será a tradução correcta e não se enquadra para o contexto, pois pelo que percebi este valor é o número de vezes que as perguntas e respostas publicadas pelo usuário foram acessadas e não a quantidade de pessoas que o usuário realmente ajudou, pois isso seria um valor um pouco difícil de se calcular e de se saber ao certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Até porque mesmo se fosse o valor de `pessoas ajudadas`, este valor seria largamente arredondado e principalmente baseado no número de votos que uma pergunta/resposta obteve e nesse caso nem todas as pessoas que acham um conteúdo útil e que lhes tenha ajudado, votam positivamente nessas publicações.
Se fosse esse o caso, a tradução - `pessoas ajudadas` se enquadraria perfeitamente neste contexto.

Mas como neste caso esse valor é uma estimativa da quantidade de visualizações que o usuário obteve em todas as suas perguntas e respostas publicadas até ao momento, então acho que a melhor tradução para aqui seria:

#### `pessoas alcançadas`

como também seria a tradução correta do texto em Inglês - `people reached`.

Comment: Isso foi discutido [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3834/4808) também (ver a explicação na resposta do Molx). No início a frase era *pessoas alcançadas* mas no histórico do Transifex consta que o Gabe alterou para *pessoas ajudadas*. Eu até enviei uma proposta para voltar o texto ao que era, lá no Transifex, mas aparentemente não foi aceita.

Answer (score 7):

Eu considero o mesmo que foi dito na resposta do [@Molx](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3835/3635):

> Ou seja, não é quantas pessoas você ajudou (até porque isso é impossível de se medir), mas quantas pessoas você pode ter ajudado, que é uma estimativa da quantidade de pessoas que leram suas perguntas e suas respostas com muitos votos.

Só adicionei a resposta para citar um detalhe, o sinal `~` a frente de números, significa "aproximado", ou seja pode ter "ajudado" 13 pessoas ou não, é apenas um valor aproximado baseado nas estatísticas citadas pelo @Molx.

Então por exemplo `~13`, é um valor aproximado ou até mesmo teórico, já que é algo que não podemos medir, então não temos como dizer que "ajudou" as 13 pessoas (a não ser que as pessoas fossem obrigadas a votar positivamente ou negativamente no momento que entrassem na postagem), mas podemos dizer que  se o intuito das postagens (perguntas e respostas) é "ajudar", então aproximadamente (ou teoricamente) 13 pessoas foram sim ajudadas.

Comment: Foi mais ou menos esse meu raciocínio. Quase todos os visitantes de uma pergunta são "ajudados em potencial". Pessoas que provavelmente tem o mesmo problema que o AP, e podem se beneficiar das mesmas respostas. Por isso o termo "pessoas ajudadas". Além disso, a expressão "pessoas alcançadas" é desprovida de qualquer sentido imediato, e o número perderia valor no perfil. O objetivo dele é fazer com que todos se sintam orgulhosos de suas colaborações, e pra isso o "ajudadas" significa muito mais.